# How to Redirect All urls to a new domain in apache, except one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect everything on one site to a new domain, except one path.

So domain.com/anything needs to go to newdomain.com/anything.

But I don't want domain.com/services/xml to redirect.

I've tried lots of conditions, but nothing works. It always ends up redirecting it, or redirecting it to some other weird path on the new domain.

This does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/services/xml$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured this out, thanks to my conversation Ansari and some help with the hosting company. The problem seems to be that the the url was being rewritten to index.php, and then it was being redirected again after that. So:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/services/xmlrpc
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.wikiweightscore.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

This works for the exact use case I was wanting.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed, also struggled with the missing index.php condition.

Answer (score 2):

Try this then:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/services/xml
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No, this still redirects everything, including the /services/xml

Comment: Well it seems to work on my end. Maybe there are other rules above this that are interfering?

Comment: This is strange. If I don't negate the condition, and just do RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/services/xml, it behaves as expected. ONLY that url is redirected. But if I negate it, everything is redirected. What in the world could cause that?

Comment: Your question said you want to redirect everything, except that one URL?

Comment: That's right. I can get it to work just the opposite way, as expected. But then add the negation (!), and it doesn't reverse it like its supposed to.

Comment: Well, like I said, it must be some other rule that is doing the rewriting, because when you go to /services/xml, this rule isn't the one being executed :) (which you just verified by affirming that the rule is fired for its opposite condition)

Comment: The only other rules are   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Is this before or after? And is /services/xml a real directory? In any case, you can try out the whole file at htaccess.madewithlove.be and see the results there.

Comment: It is not a real directory. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: In that case, if the rules you just pasted are before the additional rules I suggested, that rewrite is happening. The end result depends on what `index.php` does with that request.

Comment: Checking for /services/xml happens before those rules I just posted. So it should happen first and not matter, right? Or is there something else I'm missing? Thanks for sticking with me. I appreciate it.

Comment: It checks for /services/xml and then does what?

Comment: It just has the rules that you posted in your answer, exactly, and then it has these rules right after it: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Ohh .. in that case, what's happening is that `/services/xml` is being rewritten to `/index.php?q=services/xml` - is that what you want? Or are you saying that it goes to www.newdomain.com/services/xml instead?

Comment: Not really, that's just the Drupal default to make clean urls work. I want everything EXCEPT the path /services/xml to redirect to the new domain. 


If I take out those last lines, I get redirected to http://www.newdomain.com/index.php, which is really wrong. I don't know how it does that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem migrating to a new domain but needed to keep the services endpoints active on old domain since they were externally active. The key was including a RewriteCond for index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/services/active/endpoint$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%{ENV:protossl}://new-domain/$1 [L,R=301]
```