# Restrict a subdomain to only one kind of URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I have a Yii application hosted in an apache server. I got two sub domains pointing to the same folder like `staging.mydomain.com` and `api.mydomain.com`. 
I want all the URLS to work for the other subdomains except for api.domain.com.

For the domain api.mydomain.com , only URLs which looks like api.mydomain.com/api/{whatever} should work. All other URLs with api.mydomain.com should be 403 forbidden.

I have tried the solution mentioned here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629430/how-to-redirect-all-urls-to-a-new-domain-in-apache-except-one) .But it did n't work. Thanks

Comment: if you showed what is your .htaccess file looks like, community could help you more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule as first rule in the root .htaccess of `staging.mydomain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(api|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: just out of curiosity before checking the solution. i didn't see anything like api.domain.com/api in the code above which would help to allow those kinds of URL

Comment: i have checked your code but it does not allow api.domain.com/api/whatever comes after. It gives forbidden for all the things.

Comment: This rule will only block domain that are not `api.mydomain.com` (see update for `/api/`)

Comment: i think i did n't make it clear in question .. i want all the other domains work normally..api.domain.com should only work if it contains the URL like api.domain.com/api/whatever. When i put your code it blocked api.domain.com as well as staging.domain.com .. thanks for yourhelp anyway.

Comment: did n't help. I can access every URL for api.domain.com , as well as staging.domain.com :(

Comment: What do you mean by `I can access every URL for api.domain.com`? Didn't you say that you want to block only `http://staging.domain.com/api`? You are not helping yourself by writing an unclear question and comments. Edit your question and clearly write what URLs you want to block.

Comment: sorry for misleading you with inappropriate question. I have edited the question. If you don't understand it can we have a chat discussion.

Comment: Ok I think I understand better now. I edited my answer, try it now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51488/discussion-between-shanavascet-and-anubhava)